# LaTeX format for writing reviews for AMS

Tags: review-databases

I need to know how I can find a LaTeX template for writing reviews for American Mathamatical Society? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You mean after-publication reviews for their Mathscinet / Mathematical Reviews database, or actual referee reports for one of their journals?

Comment: Yes I mean  for their Mathscinet / Mathematical Reviews database

Comment: For book reviews: AMS has a Latex template for that.  https://www.ams.org/arc/journals/journal-produce.html#journal_packages

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a template. Just type (or copy and paste) your review into the text box, enclosing any math you need in $ signs.